# Seaborn heatmap giving same color for different values for discrete cbar

Tags: python, matplotlib, seaborn, heatmap

I have created a heatmap using seaborn, and have used discrete colorbar by giving colors as follows:

```
cmap = mpl.colors.ListedColormap(plt.cm.bwr_r([0, .35, 0.45, .5, .65, .9]))
cmap.set_under((.8, .8, .8, 1.0))
cmap
```

which gives me:
[image]

The code used to generate heatmap is:

```
fig = plt.figure(figsize= (5.5,4.5))
g = sns.heatmap(plotting_df, cmap = cmap, annot = True, annot_kws={'fontsize': '12'}, cbar_kws={'aspect': '12', 'shrink': .7})

cbar = g.collections[0].colorbar
cbar.set_ticks([-4.3, -2.9, -1.5, 0.7, 2.5, 4.2])
cbar.set_ticklabels([-5, -4, -3, 'ns', 3, 5])

plt.show()
```

which gives: [image]

The problem is that -5 and -4 seem to have the same color and -3 seems to have the color that -4 should have had. I brainstormed quite a bit but still haven't found the mistake. Any help would be appreciated.

PS:

```
plotting_df = pd.DataFrame([[0, 0,  0,  0,  0,  0,  0,  0,  0,  0],
[3, 0,  0,  0,  0,  0,  0,  0,  0,  0],
[0, 0,  0,  0,  0,  0,  0,  0,  0,  0],
[5, 5,  0,  0,  0,  0,  0,  0,  0,  0],
[0, 0,  -4, 0,  0,  0,  0,  0,  0,  0],
[0, 0,  0,  0,  -3, 0,  0,  0,  0,  0],
[0, 0,  3,  0,  0,  0,  0,  0,  0,  0],
[0, 0,  -5, 0,  -5, 0,  0,  0,  0,  0],
[0, 0,  -3, 0,  -3, 0,  0,  -4, 0,  0],
[0, 0,  0,  0,  0,  0,  0,  0,  0,  0]])
```

Comment: Please include the data as text, not an image.

Comment: You are trying to squeeze data with a range of 10 into 6 colors. There will have to be some values that share a color.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I still didn't understand the mistake in the given code, but have found a way around by using `mpl.colors.BoundaryNorm()`. (https://matplotlib.org/stable/tutorials/colors/colorbar_only.html#sphx-glr-tutorials-colors-colorbar-only-py)

And, I have also added value '4' in the color bar for symmetry. But the code works without it as well.

```
cmap = (mpl.colors.ListedColormap(plt.cm.bwr_r([0, .3, 0.45, .5, .55, .65, .9])))
bounds = [-5, -4, -3, 0, 3, 4, 5, 6]
norm = mpl.colors.BoundaryNorm(bounds, cmap.N)

fig = plt.figure(figsize= (5.5,4.5))
g = sns.heatmap(plotting_df, cmap = cmap, annot = True, cbar = True, annot_kws={'fontsize': '12'}, cbar_kws={'aspect': '12', 'shrink': .7}, norm = norm)

cbar = g.collections[0].colorbar
cbar.set_ticks([-4.5, -3.5, -1.5, 1.5, 3.5, 4.5, 5.5])
cbar.set_ticklabels([-5, -4, -3, 'ns', 3, 4, 5])
cbar.solids.set_edgecolor("k")
g.figure.axes[-1].set_ylabel('Weights', size=14)

plt.show()
```

[image]

Answer (score 0):

One mistake is that you are manually setting the colorbar tick labels and values which leads to a misleading plot. Commenting out `set_ticks` and `set_ticklabels` produces the image below. The other answer provides a solution.

[image]

Comment: I see that, but I wanted each number to have 1 color, that's why I did it with a discrete color bar and then specified the ticks. But as others pointed out the range distribution creates the problem. Using norm solved it. Thanks!